# How can I enter the symbol in picture, which is like “O”, in Latex? The symbol means "proportional to" in mathematics

Tags: symbols

How can I enter the symbol in picture, which is like “O”,  in Latex? The symbol means "proportional to" in mathematics.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: $\mathcal{O}$ ...

Comment: Turns out that `\mathcal O` matches the picture OP submits; But the concept of big O seems to be represented by `\Omicron`. At least in [wikipeida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations), big O's friends are Greek. In this (specific) case, knowing that there are thousands of O-like symbols does not help.

Comment: @Symbol1 - If you look up `\Omicron` in TeX's list of math greek symbols, you'll come up empty -- as it would merely duplicate the Latin character `O`. (The Romans took over some, but not all, Greek uppercase letters in classical times. Latin-script lowercase letters are a much later invention.) I suppose that one advantage of using `\mathcal{O}` to denote "of order of" is that it is rather unlikely to ever be confused with `0` (zero).

Comment: @Mico Comparing to `\mathcal{O}`, I would suggest using `\mathrm{O}` to represent the Greek O since other Greek letters are typeset in upright.